# Is it possible to warn in visual studio if linq is used on objects without equals and hashcode overridden

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, linq, equality

I just ran into a really annoying bug, that took all morning to fix. It turns out linq was evaluating my objects by comparing them using Equals() since I had not overridden that method it was not grouping my objects correctly.  I want to make it so my whole team will see build server warning messages if they add linq statements that evaluate Types that  have not had their Equals and GetHashCode() overridden.

I'm working in Vb.net but eventually we will be switching to C# an answer for either language would be great.

Comment: You'd have to write your own code inspection using Roslyn - not trivial, and undoubtedly a steep learning curve, but probably doable. And even with that, if the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations were not done properly, you would still get the same issue.

Comment: You could not use LINQ, and instead use your own wrapper methods around it that constrain `T` to `IEquatable` for any methods where comparisons are done on the type, but then you need to ensure nobody ever uses LINQ methods anywhere (but there) in your code.

Comment: @stuartd that will at least cause the call stack to show "our" code being executed for Equals() even if poorly implemented, and you can then step in with the debugger.

Comment: I think I might need to start here? https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/creating-your-first-code-analyzer/